# Stop animation on drag event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IqAiF

I want to stop the fruit movement when drag event is fired, the problem is '`animation`' class in wrapping all the `<li>` tag.

Any ideas?.

```
<ul>
  <li  class="x1">
    <div class="animation">
    <div class="fruit"></div>
    <span class="ant"></span>
    <span class="ant"></span>
    <span class="ant"></span>
    <span class="ant"></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

...

```
$('.fruit').draggable({
    revert: true,
    cursor: 'move',
    drag: function(){   
    },
    stop: function(){

    }
  });
```

The idea is to drag the fruit into a droppable div but the animation class is enclosing the fruit class, so if you try to drag the fruit the animation must to stop without stop the animation on all the elements inside of it.

Comment: Please insert the relevant code into the body of the question.

Comment: @forivall Hi, relevant code has been added.

Comment: Append it to the body on drag

Comment: @Zeaklous yeah now I need to know how to return it to the animation. Can you please look at the codepen.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates a nifty stop-start behaviour:

```
$('.fruit').draggable({
  revert: true,
  cursor: 'move',
  start: function(){
    $(this).parent().css('-webkit-animation-play-state', 'paused');
  },
  drag: function(){},
  stop: function(){
    $(this).parent().css('-webkit-animation-play-state', 'running');
  }
}
```

And this will do exactly what you're asking:

```
  $('.fruit').draggable({
    revert: true,
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: 'clone',
    appendto: document.body,
    start: function(e, ui){
      // don't use `display:none` so getting the position still works.
      $(this).css('opacity', '0');
    },
    drag: function(e, ui){
      // this could be improved. this is so that the revert works somewhat properly.
      var position = $(this).position();
      ui.originalposition.top = position.top;
      ui.originalposition.left = position.left;
    },
    stop: function(){
      $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    }
  });
```

see [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/eae2c4b358af3ebfae258abfe77eeace48fcefcb/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js#L253) for more information on the revert fix. You would need to monkey patch `$(this).data('uiDraggable')._mouseStop` to fix it completely.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GaIuy

Note that there are definitely other techniques to do this; I used this one because it made the best use of the tools that jQuery UI provides.